# Does w3m access image links?

Tags: w3m

To display `text/html` e-mail in mutt, I'm using w3m. Following the [EFAIL](https://efail.de/) announce, I am wondering if w3m is accessing the `<img>` tags when it render a page (not to display the image, but maybe for accessing metadata like the size or the timestamp) ? Is there a way to verify that, and if that's the case, to prevent it if it's not done by default ?